# SSRS Upload 14Mb report not working (Maximum request length exceeded.)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I know this is a stupid question, but the answers I find didn't work for me or I do something wrong?

I need to upload a 14.2Mb report to SSRS and got

```
Maximum request length exceeded.
```

I have change web.config to :

```
 httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" maxRequestLength = "16384"
```

in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.EXO\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Web.config

and
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.EXO\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Web.config

Then I did a IIS reset. After this I got this error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You say you did an IIS reset... Did you actually restart the SSRS service? SSRS does not use IIS after SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Yes, but after testing maxRequestLength = "1048576" then it Works?? So i don't understand the value of maxRequestLength, is this 10Mb or 104Mb?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I have to change the maxRequestLength = "1048576". I'm not sure why the value of 16384 did not work for a 14Mb report? But the problem is solved for me :)